# JQuery datatable with Asp.net core

Tags: jquery, datatables

```cs
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datatable").DataTable(),
    $("#datatable-buttons")
        .DataTable({
            pageLength: 25,
            lengthChange: 1,
            buttons: ["copy", "excel", "pdf", "colvis"]
        })
        .buttons()
        .container()
        .appendTo("#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)"),
    $(".dataTables_length select").addClass("form-select form-select-sm")
});
```

This is my datatable but I want to order values by DESC, I add "order:[2,"desc"]" to my code but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I made some investigations and you are asking about JQuery Datatable and this has nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Looks like you have missing square brackets:

```
order: [[1, "desc"]]
```

Code with added sort option is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datatable").DataTable(),  // DataTable initialization with default sorting

    $("#datatable-buttons")
        .DataTable({
            pageLength: 25,
            lengthChange: 1,
            buttons: ["copy", "excel", "pdf", "colvis"],
            order: [[1, "desc"]]  // Custom sorting by the second column in descending order
        })
        .buttons()
        .container()
        .appendTo("#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)"),
    $(".dataTables_length select").addClass("form-select form-select-sm")
});
```

Comment: At this code, where i am going add these? I dont think i can write into my views

Comment: You need to handle this operation on your view's cs part. And pass that object to your view. Use it in your script.

Since you did not provide all the code I cannot help more. But I believe this javascript uses some javascript datatable library which you need to investigate.

Comment: Changed the answer according to your needs.